# How does Spark on Yarn store shuffled files?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm performing a filter in Spark using Yarn and receiving the below error.  Any help is appreciated, but my main question is about why the file is not found.

**/hdata/10/yarn/nm/usercache/spettinato/appcache/application_1428497227446_131967/spark-local-20150708124954-aa00/05/merged_shuffle_1_343_1**

It appears that Spark can't find a file that has been stored to HDFS after being shuffled.

Why is Spark accessing directory "/hdata/"?
This directory does not exist in HDFS, is it supposed to be a local directory or an HDFS directory?
Can I configure the location where shuffled data is stored?

```
15/07/08 12:57:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.io.FileNotFoundException
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hdata/10/yarn/nm/usercache/spettinato/appcache/application_1428497227446_131967/spark-local-20150708124954-aa00/05/merged_shuffle_1_343_1 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(BlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:158)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT:  I figured out some of this.  The directory configured by spark.local.dir is the local directory used to store RDDs to disk as per http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely answer is that the task died. For example from OutOfMemory or other exception.

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest checking out the space left on your system. I'd say as Carlos that the task died, and that the reason is that spark could not write a shuffle file due to lack of space.

Try grepping `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` in the ./work directory of your workers.

Comment: Yep, we have observed exactly that with `FileNotFoundException`. The `No space left on device` error appeared for some job executions but not for others, for some reason.